# When is ${\bf u} {\bf v}^*$ unitarily diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

As ${\bf u}, {\bf v} \in \Bbb C^n $. Under what conditions is matrix ${\bf A} = {\bf u} {\bf v}^*$ unitarily diagonalizable?

I am thinking unitarily diagonalizable also means normal. So ${\bf A}^* {\bf A} = {\bf A} {\bf A}^*$.  Am I on the right track?

Just what to follow up what I have here.
${\bf A}  {\bf A}^* = {\bf v} {\bf u}^* {\bf u} {\bf v}^*$ and $ {\bf A}^*{\bf A}  = {\bf u} {\bf v}^* {\bf v} {\bf u}^*  $

As ${\bf u}, {\bf v} \in \Bbb C^n $, ${\bf u}^* {\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}^* {\bf v}$ should be a scalar. Therefore, ${\bf A}  {\bf A}^* = a {\bf v}{\bf v}^*$ and $ {\bf A}^*{\bf A}  = b {\bf  u} {\bf u}^*  $

As ${\bf A}^* {\bf A} = {\bf A} {\bf A}^*$, $a {\bf v}{\bf v}^* = b {\bf  u} {\bf u}^*$. So $ {\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$ should be linear dependent. Please tell me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Let’s see your calculations that $AA^*=A^*A$. Please edit your post to include them.

Comment: It seems like you're close to answering your own question. I think you should reflect on the fact that you wrote "I don't think it need any conditions", but you also wrote "so $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ should be linear dependent".

Comment: Thanks Mike and Ted!

Comment: @Doris You're exactly right: in order for $A$ to be normal, $u,v$ need to be linearly dependent.  Now you just need to show that if $u,v$ are linearly independent, then $A$ is normal.